# SEVERE:NULL Preferences during startup Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

While I compile and debug every procedure I'm getting error SEVERE: NULL Preferences during startup And oracle SQL developer getting hung.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of SQLDev are you using and what OS?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue yesterday. As I was looking for an answer, I came across this unanswered question of yours - !

However by going through how some queries of the stored procedure were written, I realized that:

1. There was another way of writing it with the same result set.
2. I was missing single quotation for a query assigned to a variable.

Thus, making those corrections, I found the problem gone - !

Answer (score 0):

keep the backup by renaming the system_cache folder at below path:

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system17.4.0.355.2349
```

The error will be gone.